# How to convert a date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a csv file and I import that file into anaconda. The result gave me a table with 3 columns for the date (year, month, day) and I want to turn these  columns into only one. How can I do ? Secondly, how can I associate these dates to a weekday value

as an example, I have 1969, 01, 01 separate into 3 columns and I want a new colum with 1969-01-01. After that I want a new column saying 1969-01-01 is 'wednesday'

see my code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("birthday_data.csv")
cols = ['year','month','day']
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df[cols])
df['name'] = df['datetime'].dt.weekday_name
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for convert to datetimes with [`Series.dt.weekday_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.0/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekday_name.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'year':[1969,2001],
         'month':[1,2],
         'day':[1,3],

})

cols = ['year','month','day']
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df[cols])
df['name'] = df['datetime'].dt.weekday_name
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
    datetime       name
0 1969-01-01  Wednesday
1 2001-02-03   Saturday
```

Or:

```
cols = ['year','month','day']
dates = pd.to_datetime(df[cols])
names = dates.dt.weekday_name
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':dates, 'name':names})
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!!  And if I want to apply this method to a long series of values and not to only 2 dates, how do I proceed ?

Comment: @AlexandreBergé - Same way, I have only 2 dates because 2 rows data sample.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how to do it (I'm a noob sorry :(). I have 15000 lines in my csv file, how do I replace the two values ​​that you have put in example by all the values ​​present in my file?

Comment: @AlexandreBergé - yes, first create `DataFrame` by `df = pd.read_csv(yourfile)` and then use my solution `cols = ['year','month','day']
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df[cols])
df['name'] = df['datetime'].dt.weekday_name
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)`

Comment: it doesn't works... I have this message : KeyError: "['year' 'month' 'day'] not in index"

Comment: @AlexandreBergé - OK, what is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: Index(['year', 'month', 'day', 'gender', 'births'], dtype='object')

Comment: @AlexandreBergé - I am confused, it means there are 3 columns `year, month, day`, so first solution working perfectly. Is possible see your all code? Please [add it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54215065/edit) to answer.

Comment: @AlexandreBergé - Code still return error? what is your pandas version?

Comment: I use the version 3.7 and yes the code still return error

Comment: @AlexandreBergé - So after `df = pd.read_csv("birthday_data.csv")` if check `print (df.columns.tolist())` what return ?

Comment: When I use : print (df.columns.tolist()) I have this message : ['year', 'month', 'day', 'gender', 'births']

Comment: @AlexandreBergé - Are data confidental? If not, is possible share it? Because no idea.

Comment: not confidential, it's just a dataset for a study. How can I send you the csv file ?

Comment: @AlexandreBergé - sent it to my email in my profile.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `read_csv` to read the excel then you can use the `date_parser` argument. You can see more info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')
#Pass the column names from your excel sheet to below (year, month, date)
df = pd.read_csv(inputfile, parse_dates={'datevalue': ['year', 'month', 'day']}, date_parser=dateparse)
```